# How do I get Facebook Application Login to work

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I just started making an application for Facebook, however I ran into problem early on. The first step I want people to do is to give permission to access their profile. All over the web are examples of how to do this with:

```
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
```

However, this is the way it works using the Old PHP API. I have downloaded and installed the new one in my application folder and it is not working anymore.

**My question is (and i really have been searching for an answer for a long time) what is the code to do this with the new API?**

(and related question: is it better to use the old API, or learn to work with the new one when I am just starting making apps right now)

I have this code now;

```
    <?php
        // Awesome Facebook Application
        //
        // Name: -
        //

        require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
        $app_id = "-";
$app_secret = "-";

        // Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday, user_location,user_work_history'
        )
);

$fbme = null;

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
else {
    try {
        $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}


echo "<p>hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" />!</p>";


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and use new code from github.

How to get user permission?

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream,sms,status_update,user_location'
));
```

Or

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,publish_stream,sms,status_update,user_location"></fb:login-button>
```

[Example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) how to login

Update

---

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday, user_location,user_work_history'
        )
);

$fbme = null;

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
else {
    try {
        $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! However, I'd like to use the first method, so no button is needed. However, it doesn't work when i put i like i did (please see updated code in my first question)

Comment: http://thinkdiff.net/category/facebook/ a lot of example how to make app with iframe, canvas, fmbl etc. good to start.

Comment: OK it works now when i run it as an IFrame, thanks! Any more tips of how to use (for example print) the data that i now can access?

Comment: example to get full name  `$fbme['name']` for more detail `print_r($fbme)` or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/